# Using the coordinate derive from maptoscene(event.pos()) to draw on cvMat image

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

Im so far trying to get the coordinate deriving from leftmouseclick function and use then to draw on the cvMat image. 
So after I left click on the graphviewer(ps. image is set the same sizes as graphviewer and setpixmap). The leftmouseclick function will get event.pos() and further operate thru maptoScene() to get the scenepos. Second, I convert the pixmap to np.ndarray and use cv.cirle with scenepos.x() and scenepos.y() to draw circle on the image. Third, I convert the np.ndarray back to pixmap and update to qgraphviewer.
I know that it sounds alit bit stupid but my question is that the drawn circle isn't at the same position where i clicked on the qgraphviewer.
Is there a shifting or something while mapping using maptoscene()???

Down below is part of the codes

```
def np2qpixmap(np_img):
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(np_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = QtGui.QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], frame.shape[1]*3, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
    return QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(img)

def QImageToCvMat(incomingImage):
    incomingImage = incomingImage.convertToFormat(4)

    width = incomingImage.width()
    height = incomingImage.height()

    ptr = incomingImage.bits()
    ptr.setsize(incomingImage.byteCount())
    arr = np.array(ptr).reshape(height, width, 4)  #  Copies the data
    return arr

class Main(QMainWindow, TestGUI.Ui_MainWindow):
    leftMouseButtonClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(float, float)
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.pixmap = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        scene.addItem(self.pixmap)
        self.graphicsView.setScene(scene)
        self.leftMouseButtonClicked.connect(self.handleLeftClick)
        self.imgroot = "./image"
        self.annoroot = ""
        self.img = None
        self.imgList = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.imgroot, "*.png"))
        self.img_num = len(self.imgList)
        self.ImageButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.AnnoButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.image_scale=1
        self.i = 0
        if self.img_num > 0:
            self.setImage()
        else:
            self.textBrowser(">> No Image in Folder")

    def UpdateImage(self, processed_image):
        if isinstance(processed_image, np.ndarray):
            self.img = np2qpixmap(processed_image)
            # self.img = QtGui.QPixmap(processed_image)
        self.pixmap.setPixmap(self.img)

    def setImage(self):
        self.img = QtGui.QPixmap(self.imgList[self.i])
        if self.img.height() > self.img.width():
            self.scale = self.img.height() / self.graphicsView.height()
            self.img = self.img.scaledToHeight(self.graphicsView.height())
            self.pixmap.setPixmap(self.img)
        else:
            self.scale = self.img.width() / self.graphicsView.width()
            self.img = self.img.scaledToWidth(self.graphicsView.width())
            self.pixmap.setPixmap(self.img)

    def PreviousImage(self):
        if self.i - 1 > - 1:
            self.i = self.i - 1
            self.setImage()
        else:
            self.ShowText(">> The First Image!!")

    def NextImage(self):
        if self.i + 1 < self.img_num:
            self.i = self.i + 1
            self.setImage()
        else:
            self.ShowText(">> The Last Image!!")

    def ShowText(self, msg):
        self.textBrowser.append(msg)

    def BrowseFolder(self):
        if self.ImageButton.isChecked():
            self.imgroot = self.getExistingDirectory()
            if os.path.isdir(self.imgroot):
                self.textBrowser.append(">> Set Image Folder : {}".format(self.imgroot))
                self.file_browser.clear()
                self.file_browser.append(self.imgroot)
                self.imgList = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.imgroot, "*.png"))
                self.img_num = len(self.imgList)
                self.i = 0
                if self.img_num > 0:
                    self.setImage()
                else:
                    self.textBrowser.append(">> No Image in Folder")
            else:
                self.textBrowser.append(">> Not a valid folder")
            self.ImageButton.setChecked(False)
        elif self.AnnoButton.isChecked():
            self.annoroot = self.getExistingDirectory()
            if os.path.isdir(self.annoroot):
                self.textBrowser.append(">> Set Annotation Folder : {}".format(self.annoroot))
                self.anno_file_browser.clear()
                self.anno_file_browser.append(self.annoroot)
                self.AnnoList = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.imgroot, "*.xml"))
            else:
                self.textBrowser.append(">> Not a valid folder")

    def getExistingDirectory(self):
        """
        Open a filedialog where you must choose a directory
        :return: The selected directory
        """
        return str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Select Directory"))

    def ClearText(self):
        self.textBrowser.clear()

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        """ Show entire image.
        """
        self.scenePos = self.graphicsView.mapToScene(event.pos())
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.leftMouseButtonClicked.emit(self.scenePos.x(), self.scenePos.y())
        QMainWindow.mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event)

    def handleLeftClick(self, x, y):
        if isinstance(self.img, QtGui.QPixmap):
            Processed_Image = QImageToCvMat(self.img.toImage())
        else:
            Processed_Image = self.img
        # Processed_Image = cv2.cvtColor(Processed_Image, cv2.CV_8UC3)
        cv2.circle(Processed_Image, (int(x), int(y)), 1, (0,0,255), 1)
        self.UpdateImage(Processed_Image)
        self.ShowText(">> Clicked on image pixel (row={}, column={})".format(self.scenePos.y(), self.scenePos.x()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Main()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please, can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? You can't expect us to understand all your code as it's missing lots of parts that could help us clarify what really happens, also your `Main` class doesn't seem to be a QObject descendant. That said, a QGraphicsPixmap is always aligned to (0, 0), as in top-left corner, and AFAIU cv2.circle uses `x` as the center, so you may probably need to add the radius to the x and y values or subclass it on your own. But, still, without a reproducible example that'd be a wild guess.

Comment: @musicamante thanks for ur prompt response. I've edit and add the entire code to post.

Comment: @musicamante it seems that I should mapFromParent instead of mapToScene

Comment: You need to use both mapFrom (the view could have a parent widget which might not be the QMainWindow) referred to the viewport and not the view, and mapToScene (since the scene could be scrolled/scaled/transformed). So, that should do the trick: `pos = self.view.mapToScene(self.view.viewport().mapFrom(self, event.pos()))`. Besides that, why/how are you tracking mouseDoubleClickEvent in the main window? It shouldn't work, as the scene (and therefore the view) should process it and avoid propagation to their parent(s).